# Creating custom AVD(Emulator) for Micro Max Funbook(480*800) 7 tab

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

How can i take Custom AVD, for examle i want to check application in  Micro Max funbook (480*800) 7 inch. Thanks in advance

Comment: With the AVD manager?

Comment: you need to have the specification first

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the AVD manager.

You just need to select the **Devices Definitions** tab and than the **New Devices...** button. There you enter the specs:
[image: Step 1]

The second step is to create a new VM as you already know it.
[image: Step 2]